# Добавление множества объектов класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Хочу чтобы этот код

```py
class GetUser():
    def __init__(self, user_id):
        fields = ['verified', 'blacklisted', 'sex', 'bdate', 'city',
                    'country', 'home_town', 'photo_50', 'photo_100',
                    'photo_200_orig', 'photo_200', 'photo_400_orig',
                    'photo_max', 'photo_max_orig', 'online', 'lists',
                    'domain', 'has_mobile', 'contacts', 'site',
                    'education', 'universities', 'schools', 'status',
                    'last_seen', 'followers_count', 'common_count',
                    'counters', 'occupation', 'nickname', 'relatives',
                    'relation', 'personal', 'connections', 'exports',
                    'wall_comments', 'activities', 'interests', 'music',
                    'movies', 'tv', 'books', 'games', 'about', 'quotes',
                    'can_post', 'can_see_all_posts', 'can_see_audio',
                    'can_write_private_message', 'timezone', 'screen_name']
        user = vkc.users.get(user_ids=user_id, fields=fields)[0]
        self.verified = user['verified']
        self.blacklisted = user['blacklisted']
        self.sex = user['sex']
        self.bdate = user['bdate']
        self.city = user['city']
        self.country = user['country']
        self.home_town = user['home_town']
        self.photo_50 = user['photo_50']
        self.photo_100 = user['photo_100']
        self.photo_200_orig = user['photo_200_orig']
        self.photo_200 = user['photo_200']
        self.photo_400_orig = user['photo_400_orig']
        self.photo_max = user['photo_max']
        self.photo_max_orig = user['photo_max_orig']
        self.online = user['online']
        self.lists = user['lists']
        self.domain = user['domain']
        self.has_mobile = user['has_mobile']
        self.contacts = user['contacts']
        self.site = user['site']
        self.education = user['education']
        self.universities = user['universities']
        self.schools = user['schools']
        self.status = user['status']
        self.last_seen = user['last_seen']
        self.followers_count = user['followers_count']
        ...
```

Был не таким большим, т.е. хочу чтобы он укоротился, но не знаю как (сразу извиняюсь если объяснил неясно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class GetUser():
    def __init__(self, user_id):
        fields = [
            'verified', 'blacklisted', 'sex', 'bdate', 'city', 'country',
            'home_town', 'photo_50', 'photo_100', 'photo_200_orig',
            'photo_200', 'photo_400_orig', 'photo_max', 'photo_max_orig',
            'online', 'lists', 'domain', 'has_mobile', 'contacts', 'site',
            'education', 'universities', 'schools', 'status', 'last_seen',
            'followers_count', 'common_count', 'counters', 'occupation',
            'nickname', 'relatives', 'relation', 'personal', 'connections',
            'exports', 'wall_comments', 'activities', 'interests', 'music',
            'movies', 'tv', 'books', 'games', 'about', 'quotes', 'can_post',
            'can_see_all_posts', 'can_see_audio', 'can_write_private_message',
            'timezone', 'screen_name'
        ]
        user = vkc.users.get(user_ids=user_id, fields=fields)[0]

        for field in fields:
            setattr(self, field, user[field])
```

Comment: работает, но при использовании параметра выдается ошибка: 'GetUser' object has no attribute 'first_name'

Comment: @LigeZet разве в `fields` у вас есть "first_name" строка?

Comment: извиняюсь за невнимание и благодарю за ответ

Comment: ещё один вопрос возник, могу ли я как нибудь убрать предупреждения о несуществовании атрибута? (сам код работает замечательно)

Comment: @LigeZet лучше задайте новый вопрос с указанием предупреждения и в каком коде оно появляется

Comment: спасибо, но проблема уже устранена (сам не знаю как, видимо изменения в коде повлияли)